# How to print a boost::variant of streamable types?

Tags: c++, boost

I feel like I'm having a serious 'Doh!' moment here...

I'm currently trying to implement:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyType &type)
```

Where MyType holds a boost::variant of int, char and bool. IE: Make my variant streamable.

I tried doing this:

```
out << boost::apply_visitor(MyTypePrintVisitor(), type);
return out;
```

And MyTypePrintVisitor has a templated function that uses boost::lexical_cast to convert the int, char or bool to a string.

However, this doesn't compile, with the error that apply_visitor is not a function of MyType.

I then did this:

```
if(type.variant.type() == int)
out << boost::get<int> (type.variant);
// So on for char and bool
...
```

Is there a more elegant solution I'm missing?
Thanks.

**Edit: Problem solved. See the first solution and my comment to that.**

Comment: According to this [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts) the variant should be directly streamable

Comment: please post real, reduced but complete code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to stream a `variant` if all its contained types are streamable. Demonstration:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct MyType
{
    boost::variant<int, char, bool> v;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyType &type)
{
    out << type.v;
}

int main()
{
    MyType t;
    t.v = 42;
    std::cout << "int: " << t << std::endl;

    t.v = 'X';
    std::cout << "char: " << t << std::endl;

    t.v = true;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "bool: " << t << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
int: 42
char: X
bool: true
```

If you do need to use a visitor (perhaps because some of the contained types aren't streamable), then you need to apply it to the `variant` itself; your snippet of code looks like it's applying it to a `MyType` object instead.

Comment: 'Doh!' moment indeed... My variant once held a custom class so when I tried to stream the variant directly it failed, thus I needed a custom solution. Since then I've simplified the variant to hold only POD types, and now when I re-visited the code I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but this does not work with clang 5.0 with C++17. But I've another solution:

```
std::variant<int, char, bool> v;
std::visit(
    [](auto value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; },
    v
);
```